# Any third party tools to map SharePoint document library as mapped network drive inside user's machine

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, onedrive, mapped-folder

We have a requirement from one of our users that he need to map a SharePoint document library as a mapped drive inside his windows 11 machine. now using the built-in Map Network

[image]

does not seem to work on all users' machines. so, is there any 3rd part tools that can achieve this? we have disable OneDrive on all the users' machine because it is causing lot of issues when syncing the large amount of files that are been added,edited,delete,moved and copied to the end users' machines.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Are you on SharePoint Online? If so, you can try [Zee Drive to map network drives to SharePoint Online and OneDrive for Business](https://www.thinkscape.com/Map-Network-Drives-To-Office-365-OneDrive/)

Comment: yes i am on sharepoint online, does this work like OneDrive where the files will be available offline (which we do not want), or it will work as a true mapped drive that will only be accessible when users are online (which we are looking for)? Thanks

Comment: Zee Drive works more like a network file server where the files are available only when connected to the server. Files are not available offline

Comment: so they mimic the Map Network drvie?

Comment: Zee Drive maps network drives to SharePoint Online and OneDrive for Business